# venv cannot find python library even though I definitely have it installed

Tags: python, virtualenv

Im runnig a windows 10 machine, and im getting started on playing with virtual enviorments. I want to run a small fastapi application

I created a venv like this:

```
python -m venv venv
```

I then activated the venv, and installed my two dependencies:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Ask\python_Projects\garse_dockerAPI\app> pip install fastapi
```

and

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Ask\python_Projects\garse_dockerAPI\app> pip install unicorn
```

Which seemed to work fine, running pip list also seems to indicate that i have what I need:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Ask\python_Projects\garse_dockerAPI\app> pip list           
Package           Version
----------------- ---------
beautifulsoup4    4.9.3    
certifi           2020.6.20
cffi              1.14.3
chardet           3.0.4
crypto            1.4.1
cryptography      3.1.1
cycler            0.10.0
fastapi           0.63.0
idna              2.10
myModule          1.0.0
Naked             0.1.31
pip               21.0.1
pycparser         2.20
pycrypto          2.6.1
pydantic          1.8.1
PyYAML            5.3.1
requests          2.24.0
setuptools        49.2.1
shellescape       3.8.1
six               1.15.0
soupsieve         2.0.1
starlette         0.13.6
typing-extensions 3.7.4.3
unicorn           1.0.2
urllib3           1.25.10
wheel             0.35.1
```

But when I run my program it fails with the inmport of the fastapI:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Ask\python_Projects\garse_dockerAPI\app> python .\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ask\python_Projects\garse_dockerAPI\app\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from fastapi import FastAPI
```

Also, running python my terminal doesnt wanna do it either:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Ask\python_Projects\garse_dockerAPI\app> python 
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fastapi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'
```

What's going on? why do i not have the dependencies i need?

EDIT:

In order to find the installation on my machine, I ran 'where python' in my normal terminal:

```
C:\Users\Ask>where python
C:\Users\Ask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
C:\Users\Ask\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Which give sme two different paths. I dont really know what to do with this information?
running where pip:

```
C:\Users\Ask>where pip
C:\Users\Ask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe
```

When I run it in my venv, the commands output nothing at all:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Ask\python_Projects\garse_dockerAPI\app> where pip
(venv) PS C:\Users\Ask\python_Projects\garse_dockerAPI\app> where python
(venv) PS C:\Users\Ask\python_Projects\garse_dockerAPI\app>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed?

Comment: this might be the case, how do I know which pytohn version that my pip in my venv is pointing to?

Comment: Type `where python`.

Comment: if I do it in regular cmd, it gives me two locations 'C:\Users\Ask\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' and 'C:\Users\Ask\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe'. Running it in the venv gives me nothing

Comment: So how do I know which python installation is connected to my pip?

Comment: did you try mentioning the specific pip version? pip34 install example

Comment: You messed up something. I'd start from scratch. Delete the virtual environment directories and try again: `python -m venv venv; ./venv/Scripts/activate; pip install fastapi unicorn; python -c 'import fastapi; print("it works")'` this should print `it works` after being able to import `fastapi`.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely recommend using `python3 -m pip` instead of pure `pip`. It might save you some headache. The reason: when I used `pip` to install new packages in a `venv` virtual environment, they ended up in my OS environment! But just using `python3 -m pip` did the trick.

To make sure that the packages are called from your virtual environment, you can use `python3 -m PACKAGE_NAME` instead of `PACKAGE_NAME`. For example, `flower` didn't work in my virtual environment, but `python3 -m flower` works with no problem.

You can *directly* ask `python` where it is executed from! Try this:

```py
>>> import sys

>>> print(sys.executable)
/PATH/TO/VENV/bin/python

>>> print(sys.version)
'3.10.5 (main, Jun  6 2022, 18:49:26) [GCC 12.1.0]'
```